# VaryByParam not working properly in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .htaccess, caching

In my MVC project I am using OutCache for caching a page. And I also use .htaccess so that for 2-3 different url it gets same page.

I am using VaryByParam to store page in cache. When I hit the any one url with some query string it store the output in cache perfectly but when I hit the different url (which redirect to the same controller as for the first one) with same query string which I used first time it will store different copy for this time.

I don't understand why it is happening as VaryByParam stores data based on Query String and not based on the URL.

Here is my code.
Controller: Main.cs

```
[OutputCache(Duration=200,VaryByParam="*")]
public ActionResult Details(Filter filter)
{
//some code
}
```

here Filter is Class to store query string based on its parameter.

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^cars/get-details/          /main/details/ [QSA,NC,L]
```

So when I hit `http://localhost/main/details/?car=1` it store page in cache and works fine if I hit same url I will get data from cache but when I hit `http://localhost/cars/get-details/?car=1` rather then fecthing from cache it store another copy for this.
I don't understand why it is happening.Any help would work.

Comment: Did you implemented IEquality in your object?

Comment: yes I did that.

Comment: what is car here?? in your method you have mentioned some other object?

Comment: In Filter there is property name car.